# Add a class to a select options row if particular select option is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a whole bunch of rows with select items in them. I want to apply a class to the row of the select item if a particular select option is selected.

At the moment I am trying this but it's not working:

```
$('#statusselect').prop("selectedIndex", 1).closest('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('waiting');     
});
```

This is the row of the DOM which is repeated several times but the select item will have different items selected:

```
<tr> 
  <td>08/11/15</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Task</td>
  <td>Name2</td>
  <td>11/11/15</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" id="statusselect" name="status_">
      <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
      <option value="Waiting">Waiting</option>
      <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am new to jquery so I am probably doing something dumb. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `change()` event listener in jQuery.

```
$('#statusselect').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Waiting")
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("green");
    else
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("green");
});
```

See a working example [on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/y0gwd70x/5/) (event listener is called on change to "waiting").

---

**EDIT**

The reason why your code is wrong is because you used `closest("tr")` on the *property* `selectedIndex` of the `#statusSelect` element, **NOT** the *element* itself, with this code:

```
... prop("selectedIndex", 1).closest('tr') ...
```

Also, because `closest()` selects only one element, there is no need for the `each()` iterator function. You can simply do this:

```
... closest('tr').addClass('waiting');
```

---

**EDIT 2**

By request, a way to add the class dynamically to all the `<select>` elements:

```
$('#statusselect').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Waiting") {
        $(this).addClass("waiting");
    }
});
```

This is essentially the same as the prior example, except that it is called on load and there is no need to `removeClass()` if it is not selected (because no element is selected on load).

Also, if you have multiple `<select>` elements, its best to put them in a `class` instead of an `id` (because `id`s are supposed to be unique), like so:

```
<select class="statusSelect">
```

and select them like so:

```
$(".statusSelect") ...
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your response this is very very helpful! Just a quick follow up how would I get the class to apply on not just a change event but also on the initial values after the page has loaded?

Comment: @user1190132 You can add it as a class with the `class` attribute in the tag in HTML (for example, `<tr class='waiting'>`

Comment: @user1190132 and I'm glad to have helped (don't forget to accept)!

Comment: Is there a way I can do this with jquery because this could be quite challenging for me as all the data is coming from mySQL?

Comment: Yeah I meant is there a way with jQuery to apply the class to all select items which have a selected option 'Waiting' after the DOM has loaded and not just after a change event occurs on the select item? Because while the code you provided works it only works after a change event occurs (which is half the story) and doesn't work on items that loaded with the 'Waiting' status.

Comment: @user1190132 Gotcha this time =). I'll update my post. There you go.